# how do i put the header static in aspx page without having css? because it always goes to bottom.

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

```
        <tr>

             <td class="table-header2"<width="200">Doctor Name</td>
             <td class="table-header2" <width="35">Segment</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Jan</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Feb</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Mar</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Apr</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">May</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Jun</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Jul</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Aug</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Sep</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Oct</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Nov</td>
             <td class="table-header2"><width="35">Dec</td>
            </tr>
```

i tried this code. but the "doctor name","segment","jan",..... appears at the bottom. can i know why? thanks in advance.

Comment: <div class="pull-left">      
           <div class="content-frame-bottom white type4" id="divFrequency" style="overflow:auto" runat="server"> </div>
             <table id ="frmain" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">                                           i put this on top. but it didnt appear in the question above.

Comment: its bcoz your html structure was invalid...

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it? @Parthi04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, fixed:

```
<div class="pull-left"> 
    <div class="content-frame-bottom white type4" id="divFrequency" style="overflow:auto" runat="server"></div> 
    <table id ="frmain" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">          
         <tr>
             <td class="table-header2" width="200">Doctor Name</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Segment</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Jan</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Feb</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Mar</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Apr</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">May</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Jun</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Jul</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Aug</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Sep</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Oct</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Nov</td>
             <td class="table-header2" width="35">Dec</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```